# Prove that $\ker T^n$ is a subspace of $\ker T^{n+1}$ for all $n\geq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I've tried to show this by the following argument:

$T:V\to V$ is a linear map. Take $n\geq 0$. Let $v\in \ker T^n$. So $T^nv=0$. Then $T^{n+1}v=T(T^nv)=T(0)=0$. Hence  $v\in \ker T^{n+1}$. Thus $\ker T^n  \subseteq \ker T^{n+1}$. Am I now allowed to say "since kernels of linear maps are subspaces, $\ker T^n$ is a subspace of $\ker T^{n+1}$ for all $n\geq 0$"?

I'm not sure if that last sentence is rigorous enough. Alternative approach: I could use subspace test.

Comment: You are correct. It is indeed a rigorous proof.

Comment: It's rigorous, but if you're uncomfortable with the argument, you can include the proof that kernels are subspaces: it's a simple one-liner.